# kill service of one app in other app

Tags: android, service

I have two different apps, this hypothesis two apps are  A and B. there are many service at A app,my task is want to kill the service of A using method of B, but A and B are not apk ,are different apps.

```
i used :
ActivityManager manager =  (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> activityes = ((ActivityManager) manager).getRunningAppProcesses();

    for (int i = 0; i < activityes.size(); i++){

        Log.e("APP: "+i, activityes.get(0).processName);

        if (!activityes.get(i).processName.contains("com.qihoo360")){
            //android.os.Process.killProcess(activityes.get(1).pid);
            Log.i("dfd","xx");
            manager.killBackgroundProcesses("com.qihoo360.mobilesafe"); 
            android.os.Process.sendSignal(activityes.get(1).pid, android.os.Process.SIGNAL_KILL);
        }

    }
```

but no useful.but at mobile setting  manager App ，it have a close button to close it. if i no authority to kill another app because System security.

Comment: kiss the service of A? ooooh.

Comment: are you cannot understand my question?

Comment: Your question is not clear, did you ensure you have the permission to kill services?

Comment: i donot know if i have the permission to kill services,what permission  i need to kill  services.i want in B app method to kill service of A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at intent-filters. Make sure your application has permission to access the service and you other application. Hopefully this link could help you out: http://justanapplication.wordpress.com/2011/02/16/the-android-intent-based-apis-part-five-services-and-intents/

Answer (score 1):

You should not even attempt to kill the service in this manner.

Use a broadcast receiver in the service to be stopped and send a broadcast from the app that wants to stop it.

This lets the receiver decide if it is finished and release resources gracefully.

You should have an extremely good reason to even attempt to forcibly kill processes.

Comment: Ok. And using a broadcast receiver in on the receiving end doesn't cut it?

Answer (score 0):

You should refer to the source code of how services are killed before you even attempt this. This will help you figure out what you need.

**DONT** try coding without some structure on what you're trying to do, and how you can achieve it.