# How can I kill other foreground activity in android?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-service, activity-manager

I want to kill **OTHER(NOT ITSELF)** foreground activity/service. I checked some methods about kill application.

1. ActivityManager.restartPackage(String packageName)
   It was deprecated since android 2.2. So I can't use this method.
2. ActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(String packageName)
   I think it only kills background activities. But I want to kill foreground services using startForeground().

Is there any method for killing **OTHER** foreground activity/service?

Comment: Please see this SO post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29710585/can-android-kill-a-foreground-activity

Comment: what you want to acheive ?

Comment: What is your purpose? If you want to kill activity before moving to next activity , you can use finish().

Comment: Probabaly the best way to go: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9325256/kill-service-of-one-app-in-other-app)

Comment: @CoasMckey I want to know how to kill other application

Comment: @Payal finish() is just kill my activity. I want to kill another application's foreground activity/service

Comment: @SamuelD Is it possible to get intent of any application's activity/service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reply myself.

I rooted my device and used NDK to use shell command.

And then using NDK, I killed some applications with this command.
su -c "am force-stop "

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use **[stopForeground(true)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopForeground(boolean))** and then call **[stopSelf()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopSelf())**

Comment: I want to kill another application's service. These methods are not available.